# no errors, var dump looks right and wont insert

Tags: php, pdo

I was wondering if any one had any ideas on the meaning of this error

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:
>   number of bound variables does not match number of tokens Database.php
>   on line 95

lines 83 - 97 database.php

```
    ksort($data);

    //$fieldNames = implode(', ', array_keys($data));   /// to be tested
    $fieldNames = implode('`, `', array_keys($data));
    $fieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($data));

    $sth = $WIdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (`$fieldNames`) VALUES ($fieldValues)");

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $sth->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }

    $sth->execute();
    $sth->closeCursor();
```

my insert for db

```
$this->WIdb->insert("WI_Members", array(
            ":email"             => $user['email'],
            ":username"          => strip_tags($user['username']),
            ":password"          => $this->hashPassword($user['password']),
            ":full_name"       => strip_tags($user['full_name']),
            ":birthday"          => $full_birthday,
            ":gender"            => $user['gender'],
            ":country"           => $user['country'],
            ":confirmed"         => $confirmed,
            ":confirmation_key"  => $key,
            ":register_date"     => date("Y-m-d")     
        ));
```

trying to re-code my site, to stop sql injection, its passed all validation,

i have done a VAR DUMP

```
["email"]=>
  string(21) "test@googlemail.com"
  ["username"]=>
  string(12) "warner"
  ["full_name"]=>
  string(6) "Jules "
  ["password"]=>
  string(128) "db0773097ac0e01005f698bc50488524f3bea68b545ad35aa8ac73ce5c3b447b82aebcab45763a650a9195caf11cf9e7fd3f6f67265f371702ef07128bb65cdf"
  ["confirm_password"]=>
  string(128) "db0773097ac0e01005f698bc50488524f3bea68b545ad35aa8ac73ce5c3b447b82aebcab45763a650a9195caf11cf9e7fd3f6f67265f371702ef07128bb65cdf"
  ["gender"]=>
  string(1) "m"
  ["birthmonth"]=>
  string(2) "02"
  ["birthday"]=>
  string(2) "22"
  ["birthyear"]=>
  string(4) "1980"
  ["country"]=>
  string(14) "United Kingdom"
  ["bot_sum"]=>
  string(2) "10"
```

i have looked over a few forums,
i have tried a number of bits, nothing seems to work, and i have been awake 24 hours trying to fix this, so figured i would try here fresh might help lol

and thank you all for your time

Comment: also, i believe i have fixed this issue:
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens Database.php on line 95

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that the number of items in your query doesn't match the number of items in the value array.

You are declaring a certain amount of parameters but the array with their value is not the same length.

Check if they match and fix accordingly to solve the issue.

Comment: thank you, i fixed that invalid parameter, by 
echo ":$key", $value;

:birthday1988-02-19:confirmation_key66490f0dcb39c0c916bd9e1a0c4f5ef4:confirmedN:countryUnited Kingdom:full_nameMaster:emailjw4241@googlemail.com:genderm:password$2a$13$cv2qWjfQM6VTCpENLdCLNOYKNJlbdwOl/y17gsKTObbeDp7a.IkqK:register_date2015-06-29:usernameGrand Master:user_id0

now im not getting any errors, but still wont insert into db.

but thank you for commenting :D

Comment: Also, i have checked all my dabatase details which are correct

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please then mark this question as fixed and open a new one with the errors you get.